# trigger an action after ajaxForm is successfully submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to put something like a 'loading' message before the ajaxForm successfully receives the data. I know we can use the success: command to trigger an action after the data is successfully received, but I am not sure how to trigger an action right before it.

```
        $('form#createInterviewPacketForm').ajaxForm({
            $('#createInterviewPacketModal').modal('hide');
            $('#loadingModal').modal('show');

            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }

        });
```

Here is what I've tried to do. So, I first hid the modal called 'createInterviewPacketModal' which contains a button that submits the data to ajaxForm and open a modal called 'loadingModal' that contains a loading message. And when the data is successfully posted, I used the alert command to display the data.

But this code gives me the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

I tried to use the beforesubmit command, but it triggered the command even before i clicked the button to submit the data to the ajaxForm.

Plz Help!

Comment: What line doe you get the error?

Comment: in which line you got this error?

Comment: You have code inside object braces, that is invalid.  Your argument to ajaxForm should be a function.

Comment: I get the error on the first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heyo,

ajaxForm have a method beforeSend that you can use, like that:

```
 $('form#createInterviewPacketForm').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#createInterviewPacketModal').modal('hide');
            $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
 });
```

Comment: OP already wrote down:- `I tried to use the beforesubmit command, but it triggered the command even before i clicked the button to submit the data to the ajaxForm.`

Comment: Sorry, it's beforeSend the method

Comment: I am not sure what mistake i've made when I tried the beforeSend method, but this one actually works! Thanks!

Comment: It works because it doesn't have the invalid syntax that I pointed out in your question, the parameter to ajaxForm in this case is a valid object, not code wrapped in object braces.